# CGI upload creates empty file

Tags: perl, upload, cgi

Hi I'm trying to upload a file using CGI and although the CGI script runs, the file that is created is empty.

I have a html file which gets the file name and passes it to a cgi script:

```
<html>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="cgi-bin/upload.pl" method="POST">
<input type="FILE" name="file">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The cgi script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
use CGI;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my $cgi = new CGI;
my $dir = 'sub';

my $name = $cgi->param('file');
print "name: $name <br />\n";
open(LOCAL, ">$dir/$name") or die "error: failed to open $dir/$name\n";
my $file_handle = $cgi->upload('file');
die "file_handle not defined\n" unless(defined($file_handle));
while(<$file_handle>) {
    print $_;
    print LOCAL $_;
}
close($file_handle);
close(LOCAL);

print "done\n";
```

The cgi script runs OK, produces no warnings, manages to create a local file and correctly gets the remote file name. However, the script appears not to read any data from the file or write any data into the local file which is empty.

I'm definitely uploading a file that contains multiple lines of data but the output of the cgi script is as follows:

```
   name: tmp.txt 
   done
```

Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: It is rather dangerous of you to use a param value in an `open` statement, especially when using the two-argument open. What if someone enters `foo; rm -rf /` as param file?

Comment: Reiterating @TLP, make sure you always use the 3-arg version of open, `open my $local, ">", "$dir/$name"` but you should definitely make sure that the filename is what you want it to be before doing that. You should die or return an error message if it doesn't pass a regular expression like `/^\w+$/`.

Comment: Another thing you might want to consider is dumping CGI in favor of [Plack](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack). CGI.pm is very old and very mature, but full of odd quirks that must stay or risk breaking thousands of scripts out in the wild that depend on those odd quirks. Also if you use Plack, your app can run as a CGI script or FastCGI or mod_perl or just about any other way a Perl program can be made into a web application.

Comment: Building on that, it is a good idea to use [taint mode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode) when dealing with data coming from non-trusted sources.

Comment: Thanks for your replies and the tips. Security is clearly an issue with the above code, though I had planned to carry these checks once I got something that was working (perhaps no excuse though).

Comment: I'm not ignoring your problem itself, I have not yet noticed anything wrong with your program. Maybe you can check to make sure the temp file is being created with content via `tmpFileName` or check `cgi_error` for a problem?

Comment: By using tmpFileName it seems that the temp file that is created in /var/tmp has no content. Calling $cgi->cgi_error at the end of the script does not return anything

Comment: Finally found the cause! /var was completely full, so the tmp files could not be created. I guess I should have checked the appropriate log file...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the `binmode` command on the FH.

Here's a Perl script that I use as a starting point for a CGI form that uploads files (displays the form *and* does the upload):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX;
use CGI::Pretty qw(:standard -any -no_xhtml -oldstyle_urls *center);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser set_message);

use Upload;

# Constants
my $FILE_DIR_INTERNAL = 'Z:\webroot\tmp';

# Variables
my $ACTION = param('action') || "";

if (! $ACTION) { UploadForm() }
elsif ($ACTION eq "UploadFile") {
  my $file = UploadFile($FILE_DIR_INTERNAL, 1);
  print "File uploaded to $file\n<pre>";
  open(F, "$file");
  while(<F>) { print }
  close(F);
}
```

And here's the Perl module used by that script:

```
package Upload;

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX;
use File::Copy;
use CGI::Pretty qw(:standard -any -no_xhtml -oldstyle_urls *center);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); # supposed to echo STDERR to browser, too

use Exporter;
our $VERSION = do{ q$Revision: 1.5 $ =~ /(\d+)\.(\d*)([^ ]*)/; sprintf "%d.%02d%s", $1, $2, $3; };
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(UploadForm UploadFile);


my $FILE_UPLOAD_PARAM = "fileUploaded";

# *************************************************************************
# FUNCTION: UploadForm
# ARGUMENTS:    
# RETURNS:  
# NOTES:    This subroutine displays the upload form.
# *************************************************************************
sub UploadForm {


  print start_center;
  print p("Upload a file from your computer:");

  # Normally, I use the "get" method for forms (params show up in URL),
  # but "post" is required for uploading files!
  # Using "post" also requires that we pass parameters thru the hidden()
  # commands down below, instead of in the URL.
  print start_multipart_form({-method=>"post", -action=>script_name});
  print filefield($FILE_UPLOAD_PARAM,"",50) . "\n";

  # Hidden parameters are "sticky", so modify the existing "action" param,
  # before trying to insert a new hidden "action" param.
  # If you don't, CGI.pm will re-use the current "action" param.
  param("action", "UploadFile");
  print hidden("action") . "\n";

  print p(submit("", "Upload File"));
  print end_form;

  print end_center;

}

# *************************************************************************
# FUNCTION: UploadFile
# ARGUMENTS:    
# RETURNS:  
# NOTES:    This subroutine handles data "posted" thru the form
#       created in UploadForm().
# *************************************************************************
sub UploadFile {

  my $dir = shift || die "ERROR!  No arg passed to UploadFile().\n";
  my $overwrite = shift || 0;

  my $TEMP_FH;

  # The upload() function returns the filename and a file handle.  See CGI.pm.
  $_= $TEMP_FH = upload($FILE_UPLOAD_PARAM);

  # What do all the regexes do?  I wrote them, but I forgot.  I think they
  # strip off any path information (common in IE!) to get just the filename.
  s/\w://;
  s/([^\/\\]+)$//;
  $_ = $1;
  s/\.\.+//g;
  s/\s+//g;
  my $filename = $_;
  my $serverFullFilename = "$dir/$filename";

  if (! $filename) {
    DisplayErrorPage("Illegal filename: '$filename'");
  }

  if ((! $overwrite) && (-e $serverFullFilename)) {
    die "Unable to upload file.  File '$filename' already exists.";
  }

  open(SERVER_FH,">$serverFullFilename") || die "Error opening $filename for writing.";
  binmode SERVER_FH;

  # Copy the file from the temp dir to the final location.
  while (<$TEMP_FH>) {
    print SERVER_FH;
  }

  close(SERVER_FH);
  close($TEMP_FH);

  if ((stat $serverFullFilename)[7] <= 0) {
    unlink $serverFullFilename;
    die "Unable to upload file '$filename'.  This is usually due to the user specifying an invalid or unreadable file on the user's computer.";
  }

  return $serverFullFilename;
} 

return 1;
```

Forgive any inconsistencies, as I had to cut out some site-specific stuff, but if I trimmed it all correctly, that should work "out of the box"

Comment: Thanks, that module looks useful! I'll investigate when I get a chance. Although at the moment, given the uploaded file in /var/tmp is empty, it seems to me that this won't fix my current problem...

Comment: It might be because of my first comment about using binmode.  Did you ever get this work?